# ionic 2: 'ioni-compiler' plugin typescript errors

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i just run my app with "ionic serve" command and i get this error

```
> ionic-hello-world@ watch C:\Users\adirz\myapps\eventapp
> ionic-app-scripts watch
[14:39:48]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.30
[14:39:48]  watch started ...
[14:39:48]  build dev started ...
[14:39:48]  clean started ...
[14:39:48]  clean finished in 10 ms
[14:39:48]  copy started ...
[14:39:48]  bundle dev started ...
I'm the Hulk
[14:39:49]  lint started ...
[14:39:49]  copy finished in 253 ms
[14:39:49]  lint finished in 590 ms
[14:39:52]  C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts(26,11): error TS1005: ';' expected.

[14:39:52]  C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts(26,18): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
[14:39:52]  C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts(26,38): error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
[14:39:52]  C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts(34,4): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[14:39:52]  C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts(35,23): error TS1005: ',' expected.
[14:39:52]  C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts(35,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
[14:39:52]  C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts(43,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

[14:39:52]  bundle dev failed:  Error transforming C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts with 'ion-compiler' plugin: There were TypeScript errors transpiling

[14:39:52]  Error: Error transforming C:/Users/adirz/myapps/eventapp/src/app/app.component.ts with 'ion-compiler' plugin: There were TypeScript errors transpiling
    at Object.transpile (C:\Users\adirz\myapps\eventapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:39:15)
    at Object.transform (C:\Users\adirz\myapps\eventapp\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\plugins\ion-compiler.js:26:36)
    at C:\Users\adirz\myapps\eventapp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:8270:35

Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/**/*, !www/**/*.map
√ Running dev server:  http://localhost:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

ionic $
```

this is my app.module.ts- i don't see any something missing like the cmd shows the error

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

// Import pages
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { ResetPasswordPage } from '../pages/reset-password/reset-password';
import { SignupPage } from '../pages/signup/signup';

// Import providers
import { AuthData } from '../providers/auth-data';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    ResetPasswordPage,
    SignupPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    ResetPasswordPage,
    SignupPage
  ],
  providers: [
  AuthData,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

i tried to figure out what is it but i really don't see any problem.

Comment: Syntax looks good. Did you double check your import paths?

Comment: in this file? no. you can see.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by change my constructor in app.component.ts, i had some lines that has to be before other lines and it make the problem.
in addition, check all the spelling and component and check if it correct names.